# PostgreSQL not using GIN index on JSONB

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have a table with `jsonb` column `additional_fields` with following structure:

```
{
    "1": {"value": "value1"},
    "2": {"value": "value2"},
    "3": {"value": "value3"},
    "4": {"value": "value4"},
    "5": {"value": "value5"},
}
```

Each row can have different set of values.

```
          Table "public.serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"
      Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |             Default              
-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id                | integer                     |           | not null | generated by default as identity
 object_name       | character varying(255)      |           | not null | 
 additional_fields | jsonb                       |           | not null | 
 object_type_id    | integer                     |           | not null | 
 line              | geometry(LineString,4326)   |           |          | 
 point             | geometry(Point,4326)        |           |          | 
 polygon           | geometry(Polygon,4326)      |           |          | 
 organization_id   | integer                     |           | not null | 
 deleted_at        | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 is_deleted        | boolean                     |           | not null | 
 creation_date     | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
```

I have following indexes for this table:

```
Indexes:
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "additional_fields" gin (additional_fields jsonb_path_ops)
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1_line_ab5cafc4_id" gist (line)
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1_object_type_id_ffe1d322" btree (object_type_id)
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1_organization_id_e0f4e744" btree (organization_id)
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1_point_41958335_id" gist (point)
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1_polygon_2bc6ffb1_id" gist (polygon)
```

When i'm using search only by `additional_fields` PostgreSQL use GIN index with good performance ~100 ms:

```
SELECT "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."id",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."is_deleted",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."deleted_at",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."object_name",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."object_type_id",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."organization_id",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."point"::BYTEA,
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."line"::BYTEA,
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."polygon"::BYTEA,
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."creation_date"
FROM "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"
WHERE (NOT "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."is_deleted"
                            AND ("serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"1": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"2": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"3": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"4": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"5": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"6": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"7": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"8": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"9": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"10": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"11": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"12": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"13": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"14": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"15": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"16": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"17": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"18": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"19": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"20": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"21": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"22": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"23": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"24": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"26": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"27": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'))
```

Query plan:

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Bitmap Heap Scan",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Async Capable": false,
      "Relation Name": "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1",
      "Alias": "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1",
      "Actual Rows": 2,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Recheck Cond": "((additional_fields @> '{\"1\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"2\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"3\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"4\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"5\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"6\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"7\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"8\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"9\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"10\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"11\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"12\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"13\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"14\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"15\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"16\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"17\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"18\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"19\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"20\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"21\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"22\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"23\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"24\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"26\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"27\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb))",
      "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
      "Filter": "(NOT is_deleted)",
      "Rows Removed by Filter": 0,
      "Exact Heap Blocks": 2,
      "Lossy Heap Blocks": 0,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "BitmapOr",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Async Capable": false,
          "Actual Rows": 0,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"1\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"2\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"3\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"4\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"5\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"6\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"7\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"8\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"9\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"10\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"11\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"12\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"13\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"14\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"15\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"16\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"17\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"18\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"19\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"20\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 2,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"21\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"22\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"23\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"24\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"26\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Bitmap Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Member",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Index Name": "additional_fields",
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Index Cond": "(additional_fields @> '{\"27\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Triggers": [
    ]
  }
]
```

But when i have search statements with other fields (`id` and `object_name`) PostgreSQL uses Seq scan with bad performance ~1000-1500 ms:

```
SELECT "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."id",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."is_deleted",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."deleted_at",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."object_name",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."object_type_id",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."organization_id",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields",
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."point"::BYTEA,
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."line"::BYTEA,
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."polygon"::BYTEA,
    "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."creation_date"
FROM "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"
WHERE (NOT "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."is_deleted"
                            AND (UPPER("serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."id"::text) = UPPER('XTY529265H0006640')
                                                OR UPPER("serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."object_name"::text) LIKE UPPER('%XTY529265H0006640%') 
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"1": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"2": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"3": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"4": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"5": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"6": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"7": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"8": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"9": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"10": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"11": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"12": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"13": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"14": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"15": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"16": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"17": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"18": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"19": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"20": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"21": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"22": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"23": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"24": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"26": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'
                                                OR "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1"."additional_fields" @> '{"27": {"value": "XTY529265H0006640"}}'))
```

Query plan:

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Async Capable": false,
      "Relation Name": "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1",
      "Alias": "serviced_object_v1_servicedobjectv1",
      "Actual Rows": 2,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Filter": "((NOT is_deleted) AND ((upper((id)::text) = 'XTY529265H0006640'::text) OR (upper((object_name)::text) ~~ '%XTY529265H0006640%'::text) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"1\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"2\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"3\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"4\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"5\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"6\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"7\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"8\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"9\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"10\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"11\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"12\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"13\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"14\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"15\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"16\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"17\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"18\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"19\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"20\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"21\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"22\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"23\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"24\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"26\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb) OR (additional_fields @> '{\"27\": {\"value\": \"XTY529265H0006640\"}}'::jsonb)))",
      "Rows Removed by Filter": 11839
    },
    "Triggers": []
  }
]
```

Comment: You have at least one criteria that would defeat index usage (LIKE '%...%').

Comment: Consider implementing composite indexes that combine the JSONB field with other frequently queried columns. This approach can help the database leverage index scans more effectively, avoiding inefficient sequential scans.

Answer (score 0):

Since object_name has no usable index for this query (and apparently no index at all), there is no way to BitmapOr it.  In order to build a bitmap for it, you would have to scan the whole table.  PostgreSQL has no provision for doing that, since if you are going to scan the whole table to generate one of many bitmaps, why not just scan the whole table to get the answer directly?

You will need to build a suitable index, or change your query, or both.

For example you could create an index `using gin (object_name gin_trgm_ops)` and then use ILIKE rather than LIKE and drop the upper() calls.  but you woudl likely also need to do something with the remaining column also referenced in your massive OR tree.